# ImportError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy' w/ 2 Versions of Python Installed

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Tried running a file with the following imports:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
```

Received the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

SQLAlchemy is installed. Still, I tried to reinstall into the directory in which it will be used. I got this:

```
The directory '/Users/_/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/_/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-SQLAlchemy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (2.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask-SQLAlchemy) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy>=0.8.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask-SQLAlchemy) (1.2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-SQLAlchemy) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-SQLAlchemy) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-SQLAlchemy) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-SQLAlchemy) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->Flask>=0.10->Flask-SQLAlchemy) (1.0)
```

The bit about me not owning the directory is incorrect. I'm the only one on this machine. I own everything.

Anyway, I go back to rerun the file and get the same error message. So, it's installed, but not installed or, at the very least, not available to me.

One error message I saw when I commented out one of the import statements read as follows:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py
```

I have no clue how to fix this and get SQLAlchemy up and running. I've burned over 1.5 hours on it. The last error listed suggests having 2 versions of python may have something to do with it.

Your thoughts on a remedy would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're using Python 2, try adding `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: It's also possible you have a mismatch between your pip and python versions (i.e. you are still pointing to pip for python2, so it thinks flask_sqlalchemy is installed, but then running with python3). Hard to judge without seeing your environment what is going on here

Comment: Can you show the output of `which python` (or show which REPL comes up when doing `python` on your cmd line). And give output of `pip --version`?

Comment: pip --version yields 2.7

Comment: How are you running the project? It looks like you are installing packages in your Python 2.7 environment with pip but running with Python 3. Maybe try `python3 -m pip install flask-sqlalchemy' to install it into your Python 3 env.

Comment: Yes, I suspect you're running python3 with pip for python2.7. So the libs aren't installed correctly for Python3. You can either run with python2, or use `pip3` and reinstall your libs

Comment: Everything came in from a requirements.txt import file. Since Flask-Sessions is required, and that's a Python 2x thing, I assume it wants all Python 2x.

Comment: @MattMessersmith So, making the path change you suggested will do this?

Comment: Use `pip3` instead of `pip` when installing from requirements.txt if you want Python3.

Comment: No, you're bound to get bad results if you update your PYTHONPATH to point to Python2 libs while trying to run Python3. It might work for some of them, but will probably fail at some point.

Comment: @MattMessersmith Ok, given that I needed to use plain pip (no choice in the matter), what fix do I need.

Comment: If you can't change which pip you're using, then you need to make sure you're executing with Python2, not Python3. You've installed the libs for Python2 (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @MattMessersmith Ok, and to do that, change path or something else? Never had any issue remotely like this.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to modify PATH to ensure that Python2 is on it before Python3. Or just call Python2 the long way (on linux/mac it's `/usr/bin/python` by default, on windows it's `C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\python` by default, but it could be anywhere, idk what your system looks like)

Comment: @MattMessersmith I'm on a Mac, so I'll try something like this: PYTHONPATH="/Me/Documents/mydir:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH   --Thanks for your help!

Comment: I find it odd you can change your PATH by can't point to Python3's version of pip lol. Alternatively, you could just point to python3's pip. By default on linux I forget where the heck it is b/c I am currently on a windows box. My Python3's pip on windows is located at `C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe`

Comment: Wait, not PYTHONPATH, but just your regular PATH for getting Python2 instead of Python3...PYTHONPATH can only be used to point to Python libs (after you are running python), but it won't tell your OS which Python to start

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how paths work or ./bash files. I've just done objs/algorithms/etc. This other stuff is the type of thing that has always just worked. And now, well, it isn't, so time to pay the piper. lol

Comment: Hahaha. Don't worry, you'll pick it up. The PATH environment variable is special on all common OS's (Windows/Mac/Linux). It's what tells your shell where to look for executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, I resolved this issue ages after I posted the above question.

The fix was to run all package updates and installs thru Anaconda and do my work in Spyder.

The lesson learned was simple: Once you start using Anaconda as your go-to environment for all things Python, all updates -- made via conda install or pip -- will be orchestrated and placed in your system by Anaconda by default.

Comment: if you use anaconda, try to avoid using also pip installs, since it can cause dependencies problems. It's better to use a different environment for a different project either if you use conda, virtualenv, or poetry to manage it.

Answer (score 8):

I think you have a mismatch between your pip and python versions. 
check your pip version **pip --version**, 
if it is pip3
you can try this,

```
sudo apt-get install python3-sqlalchemy
```

This should work.

```
~$ python3

>>import sqlalchemy
```

Comment: doing a `which pip` in linux could help you find your pip path and make sure it is in accordance with `which python`

Answer (score 6):

If you are on mac, try 
`pip install flask-sqlalchemy` 
instead of
`pip3 install flask-sqlalchemy`.

It works with some warnings, but was able to succesfully connect to the database and create the tables.
"FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning."

Comment: *Thanks*. It worked for me. I was trying to debug it for a long time

Answer (score 4):

Did you install [flaskext.sqlalchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/)? It looks like you may have only installed the `SQLAlchemy` package and NOT the Flask Extension. Try `pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy`

Answer (score 4):

This issue main occurs when we are run the flask with cmd `flask run` in the `virtual environment`

**Reason**

This happens when run the flask from `flask run` command

`flask-sqlalchemy` consider the path of `python` or `python3` rather than `virtaul environment` installed packages path

**Solution**

- `Open new terminal` *or* `deactivate virtual environment`
- install *flask-sqlalchemy* in global environment `pip install flask-sqlalchemy`
- Then activate `virtual environment` and run the *commands*

  - In Ubuntu/ Mac

    ```
    export FLASK_APP=app
    export FLASK_ENV=development
    flask run
    ```
  - In Windows

    ```
    SET FLASK_APP=app
    SET FLASK_ENV=development
    flask run
    ```

Comment: OK, but why this workaround ?
Purpose of Virtualenv is that it should be separated, right ?
And it should be installed via pip separately ?
Why not working standard way ? Is a bug ?

Answer (score 3):

**Reason**

This happens when run the flask from `flask run` command in the `virtual environment`

- Error occurs due to `pip install flask` or installed `flask` in *globally*
- When we run `flask run`, the `python` or `python3` complier first check *global* package of `flask` and if not exist `flask` then check in the `virtual environment`
- If `python` or `python3` detect the `flask` in *globally* then `flask` package will import other packages like `SQLAlachemy`, `Migrate`, etc from *global packages*

**Solution**

- Open `new` terminal or `deactivate` virtual environment
- uninstall the `flask` in the *global packages* `pip uninstall flask` or `pip3 uninstall flask`
- Then go back to `virtual environment` terminal

  - Run the flask `flask run`

  or
- `activate` *virtual environment* and run the commands

  > In Ubuntu/ Mac
  >
  > ```
  > export FLASK_APP=app
  > export FLASK_ENV=development
  > flask run
  > ```

  > In Windows
  >
  > ```
  > SET FLASK_APP=app
  > SET FLASK_ENV=development
  > flask run
  > ```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly it is a pip path issue. If using conda virtual env (with anaconda or miniconda), check `which pip` and `which python` in linux (find your pip and python path) and make sure they're aligned. Fix your pip path issue or instead of `pip install flask_sqlalchemy` do a

```
<ANACONDA or MINICONDA PATH>/envs/<ENV_NAME>/bin/pip install flask_sqlalchemy
```

in order to install the package in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite likely that you might have installed the particular project in a virtual environment but then forgot to assign the venv intepreter as your project's intepreter. If you're using pycharm, go to File > Settings > Project Intepreter, and select the correct intepreter for your project from the dropdown list.

The window would also show you all the packages installed on that particular intepreter so you can confirm that you have actually installed SQLAlchemy.

Comment: No clue what pycharm is. To the best of my knowledge, don't need it here.

Comment: Oh, I incorrectly assumed that you were using pycharm as your IDE, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me, hope you find it usefull:

first, uninstall flask and flask_sqlalchemy globally, open a cmd and run:

`pip uninstall flask`
`pip uninstall flask_sqlalchemy`

then, activate your project's virtual environment, in my case:

`.\venv\Scripts\activate`

then install flask and flask_sqlalchemy locally. Make sure at the beginning of the command line says something like (venv):

`pip install flask`
`pip install flask_sqlalchemy`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

1. If you use virtual environment, firstly you should check whether you are under right environment when you are installing new packages. Since if you use pycharm as IDE and conda as virtual env manager, pycharm won't automatically active the environment of your interpreter in terminal. Example: (base) -> (myenv)
2. Use pip3 as package installer. Sometimes problems popped up because of different versions of python in your computer. `pip3 install flask_sqlalchemy`

packages installed by pip will be under python2.x/site-packages, while that of pip3 will be under python3.x/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently. The following steps resolved my issue:

Ensure you are importing flask

`from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`

Flask sqlalchemy tutorial https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/

Also, ensure your env is "activated" before executing your code.

I am using Python 2.7 and pip 20.0.2

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed and nothing seems to change add this line of code to **init**.py

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

to turn off the track notifications error

Answer (score 0):

for **anaconda** users.

I tried almost all the solutions above, no one helped me,

but I tried to open **anaconda navigator** and launched **vsCode** from anaconda navigator, that's what solved the problem, I think there are some conflicts between working environments.

**Note:** you should keep **the anaconda navigator** opened !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was using PyCharm and encountered the same problem. The solution to this is to open the terminal and make your current directory the file which contains your python program. Then after that install the required package i.e. pip install flask_sqlalchemy . After that it works.