# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy.orm'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

In the CS50's Web Programming with Python and JavaScript 2018 course i got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy.orm' error. I tried to import scoped_session, sessionmaker. Any solution please?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620139/importerror-no-module-named-flask-sqlalchemy-w-2-versions-of-python-installe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'flask\_sqlalchemy' w/ 2 Versions of Python Installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620139/importerror-no-module-named-flask-sqlalchemy-w-2-versions-of-python-installe)

Answer (score 0):

from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker